# Mod Rewrite question

Tags: mod-rewrite

Does any body no any good mod rewrite tutorials for beginners?

And does any body know how to rewrite a sub directory using mod rewrite for example `http://www.example.com/sub/index.php?a=fruit` will be `http://www.example.com/sub/fruit`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) should get you started. It also has an example very similar to what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

[Start Rewriting](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-syntax)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub/([^/]*)$ /sub/index.php?a=$1 [L]
```